# difference between '@' and '=' when testing directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to get my head around testing directives at the moment and have come across some strange behaviour. My code is as follows:

```
angular.module('tddApp', [])

.directive('oddsButton', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div class="odds-btn"></div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            market1: '=',
            market2: '@'
        }
    };
});

describe('Odds Button Directive Test Suite', function() {
    var $scope,
        scope,
        elem,
        html;

    beforeEach(module('tddApp'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        html = '<div odds-button market1="market" market2="market"></div>';

        inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $scope.market = '2/1';
            elem = angular.element(html);
            $compile(elem)($scope);
            scope = elem.isolateScope();
             scope.$apply();
        });

    });

    it('should be created and replace html', function () {
        expect(elem[0].className).toContain('odds-btn');
    });

    it('should have market in isolate scope', function() {
        expect(scope.market1).toBe('2/1');
        expect(scope.market2).toBe('2/1');
    });
});
```

When I pass in market to the isolate scope using the 2 way binding '=' everything works as expected but when I pass as read only '@' it's getting the string 'market' instead of the parent scope value.

http://jsfiddle.net/6dcpo9ad/

Any thoughts greatly appreciated

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass it with '@' it really only gonna read the VALUE passed in the attribute. It won't try to resolve the variable thats behind it.

So you need to tell angular to resolve the variable to its value with the `{{}}` Pattern.

Change the html to this:

```
html = '<div odds-button market1="market" market2="{{market}}"></div>';
```

It works for me then.